# get 3 items with the highest values from JavaScript dictionary

Tags: javascript

i have something like `dict = {"apple": 1, "orange":10,"watermelon":5, "banana":15}` how i can get the 3 highest keys .

`//output ["banana","orange", "watermelon"]`

Comment: this might help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60105631/top-highest-values-in-an-object-more-if-there-are-more-max-values-and-they-are

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Top highest values in an object (more if there are more max values and they are the same)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60105631/top-highest-values-in-an-object-more-if-there-are-more-max-values-and-they-are)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Object.entries` and some destructuring to `sort`, `slice` the first 3 elements of the sorted entries array, then `map` to create the array of fruit names:

```js
const dict = {"apple": 1, "orange":10,"watermelon":5, "banana":15};
const top3 = Object
  .entries(dict) // create Array of Arrays with [key, value]
  .sort(([, a],[, b]) => b-a) // sort by value, descending (b-a)
  .slice(0,3) // return only the first 3 elements of the intermediate result
  .map(([n])=> n); // and map that to an array with only the name

console.log(top3);
```